# Pyspark Streaming transform error

Tags: spark-streaming

Hi I am new to Pyspark Streaming.

```
numbers0 = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])

numbers1 = sc.parallelize([2,3,4,5,6])

numbers2 = sc.parallelize([3,4,5,6,7])

stream0 = ssc.queueStream([numbers0, numbers1, numbers2])

stream0.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(20)
ssc.stop()
```

This works fine but as soon as I do the following I get an error:

```
stream1 = stream0.transform(lambda x: x.mean())

stream1.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination(20)
ssc.stop()
```

What I want is stream that only consists of the mean of my previous stream.
Does anyone know what I must do?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: By using transform this way, you will have 3 entries which are means of each RDD.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting when calling transform is because it requires an RDD-to-RDD function as stated in [Spark's documentation for the transform operation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transform-operation). When mean is called on an RDD, it does not return a new RDD and therefore the error.

Now, from what I understand you want to calculate the mean of each RDD that consists the DStream. The DStream is created with the queueStream and since the named parameter oneAtATime is left to default, your program will consume one RDD at every batch interval.

To calculate the mean for each RDD, you would normally do this inside a [forEachRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) output operation like this

```
# Create stream0 as you do in your example

def calculate_mean(rdd):
    mean_value = rdd.mean()
    # do other stuff with mean_value like saving it to a database or just print it

stream0.forEachRDD(calculate_mean)

# Start and stop the Streaming Context
```